# Dask distributed - clients import numpy at startup

Tags: python, numpy, dask

I'm currently moving a data analytics and diagnostics suite to dask.

The structure of the program is such that a master process distributes incoming work
packages to a group of workers. The workers calculate various diagnostics on this data.

A simple call may look like:

```
def calculate(self, dask_client, fft_future):
    def coherence(fft_data, ch_it):
        """Kernel that calculates the coherence between two channels.
        Input:
        ======    
        fft_data: ndarray, float: Contains the fourier-transformed data. 
                  dim0: channel, dim1: Fourier Coefficients. dim2: STFT bins 
        ch_it: iterable, Iterator over a list of channels we wish to perform our computation on

        Returns:
        ========
        coherence, float.
        """

        import numpy as np

        c1_idx = np.array([cc[0].ch1.idx() for cc in ch_it])
        c2_idx = np.array([cc[0].ch2.idx() for cc in ch_it])

        X = fft_data[c1_idx, :, :]
        Y = fft_data[c2_idx, :, :]

        Pxx = X * X.conj()
        Pyy = Y * Y.conj()

        Gxy = np.mean((X * Y.conj()) / np.sqrt(Pxx * Pyy), axis=1)
        Gxy = np.fabs(Gxy).real

        return(Gxy)

    self.futures_list = [dask_client.submit(coherence, fft_future, ch_iter) for ch_iter in self.get_dispatch_sequence()]
```

In the code above, numpy is imported within the function 'coherence'. I would like to accelerate
the execution by importing numpy when I create the workers instead. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Numpy is already imported by default if it is present when you import `dask.distributed`

However in general if you want to trigger code to run at Worker startup there are a variety of mechanisms mentioned here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/custom-startup.html